# "Script error." in CS-Cart

Tags: javascript, html, css, cs-cart

CS-Cart seems to break with a "Script error." HTML with a red box around. It's like I'm getting redirected, but I can't see it anywhere. I have no idea how to debug it and what data would be useful for this issue

Comment: Mention the error that you get

Comment: It’s just “Script error.” in a red box. No web server error log,  its client-side

Comment: This error comes in cs-cart when their is error related to JavaScript.
but it is showing in your site it could be mean that you have enabled error mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try to comment the following lines

```
//define('DEVELOPMENT', true);
// Enable DEV mode if Product status is not empty (like Beta1, dev, etc.)
//if (PRODUCT_STATUS != '' && !defined('DEVELOPMENT')) {
// ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
//  ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
//   define('DEVELOPMENT', true);
```

Comment: indeed. it’s undocumented as far as i know. thank you!